# Shell Script : If a string is present in a file

Tags: shell, scripting

I am a newbie to shell scriptng and I want to check if 3 strings("hello","who","when " etc) are present in  a file.
I find many ways when I google out awk,cat ,grep etc ,What can be the best way and how Can I do it.
I just need to know if the strings are present or not .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little incomplete:

- do you want to find *strings* or *words*? So when the word `Othello` appears, does that count as `hello`?
- in your question there is whitespace behind the `when`. Is that intentional?
- do you want to know whether *all three* words are in the file, or is *one of the words* enough?

The general solution is to use `grep` or `egrep` to search for text in a file. The exact command line depends on the answers to the above questions.

- to search for words (`Othello` doesn't count as `hello`) you need to pass the `-w` option to grep.
- I'm assuming thhat the whitespace was a mistake.

When you need all the words, you can do `egrep -wo 'hello|who|when' | sort -u`. The `egrep` command finds all instances of the given words, and prints them out one per line. At that point, you will have many duplicates. Therefore the `sort -u` command sorts them and only keeps the *unique* lines (that's what the `-u` means). In a complete program, I would do it as follows:

```
filename="story.txt"
words=$(egrep -wo 'hello|who|when' "$filename" | sort -u)
n=$(echo "$words" | wc -l)
if [ $n = 3 ]; then
  echo "found all words in the file"
else
  echo "didn't find all words, only \""$words"\"."
fi
```

There's a lot more that I could tell you about this little piece of code, and why I wrote it exactly like that, but for a beginner, it's already enough to understand.

But just in case that you need a simple solution and the file is small anyway, so performance is not critical, you can do this:

```
filename="story.txt"
if egrep -wl 'hello' "$filename" 1>/dev/null; then
  if egrep -wl 'when' "$filename" 1>/dev/null; then
    if egrep -wl 'who' "$filename" 1>/dev/null; then
      echo "found all three words"
    fi
  fi
fi
```

[Update:]

This second code snippet also checks whether the given file contains *all* three words. Each of the `if` clauses checks for one of the words. The option `-l` (lowercase ell) to `egrep` makes it potentially faster, but you probably don't need that option at all.

Normally `egrep` prints all lines that match the given expressions (your three words in this case). Since we don't need that output, we redirect it using the arrow operator `>` to a special file called `/dev/null`. Whatever you write into that file is discarded.

The `if` statement takes another command as its argument, and if that command returns successfully, the `then` branch is taken. The nice thing about the `egrep` command is that it returns successfully iff the given search expression is contained in the file, so these two things perfectly fit together.

For further reading you should try the reference documentation from the Open Group website: http://www.google.com/search?q=opengroup+grep

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info .. it helps a lot..                   I want words and the space after when was accidental                                                         I want to know if all three words are ther ,then only I want to do some processing                                                       But I did not get whats the difference between your two approaches and please throw some light on second approach as U did for the first ,thanks A lot

Comment: Also what does -wo in egrep -wo stand for.is it egrep -w ?

Comment: The `-wo` option is a shortcut for the two options `-w -o`. The `-w` option lets you find *words* instead of *substrings*, and the `-o` option prints only the text that is matched by the search expression, not the whole line in which the text was found. (But I just saw that both of these options are not guaranteed by POSIX, so you need to check whether your system supports them. Linux does.)